# no wireless on aspire one d257 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, acer

I´m lost in wireless Connection.
After Installation of ubuntu, there is no wireless driver availalble ("wireless" not appearing in the menue). Strange, as it worked when starting ubuntu from CD....
Installing the additional wireless STA driver fails.

Using: 
Acer Aspire one d257 with broadcom BCM 4313 802 11b/g/n wireless Adapter;
Ubuntu 12.04

Please excuse me being a simple user only, not an expert and yes, I still staggered per tons of tipps how to solve the Problem.

If possible, please post a SIMPLE instruction how to solve the Problem.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Also you may want to take a look at  [WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access)

Comment: not successfull: aborts Installation with message "unsupported device found: PCI-ID 14e4i4727"